# TypeError: req.session.regenerate is not a function using Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

Hello I'm following the course Node with React full web stack, and I got a big issue, I don't know why it's showing up, or from what is showing up.
my terminal shows this error  :

```
req.session.regenerate(function(err) {
               ^ TypeError: req.session.regenerate is not a function
```

and my code looks like it

index.js

```
 const express = require("express");
 const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
 const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
 const passport = require("passport"); 
 const keys = require("./config/keys"); 
 require("./models/User");
 require("./services/passport");
 
mongoose.connect(keys.connect_url);

const app = express();

app.use(   cookieSession({
     maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
     keys: [keys.cookieKey],   }) ); 
app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session());

require("./routes/authRoutes")(app);
 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; 
app.listen(PORT);
```

passport.js

```
     const passport = require("passport"); 
     const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy; 
     const mongoose = require("mongoose");
     const keys = require("../config/keys");
     
     const User = mongoose.model("users");
     
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {   done(null, user.id); });
 
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {  
    User.findById(id).then((user) => {
       done(null, user);   }); });
    
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(
         {
           clientID: keys.googleClientId,
           clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
           callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
         },
         (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
           User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }).then((existingUser) => {
             if (existingUser) {
               // we already have a record with the given profile ID
               done(null, existingUser);
             } else {
               // we don't have a user record with this ID, make a new record!
                new User({ googleId: profile.id })
               .save()
                 .then((user) => done(null, user));
             }
           });
         }   ) );
```

authRouters.js

```
        const passport = require("passport");
    
    module.exports = (app) => {
      app.get(
        "/auth/google",
        passport.authenticate("google", {
          scope: ["profile", "email"],
        })
      );
    
      app.get("/auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google"));
    
      app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.user);
      });
    };
```

I really don't know from it issue comes in, I can say that is showing up when I'm going to `localhost:5000/auth/google`

Answer (score 56):

Am doing the same course, fix is there on udemy. From Udemy :

Passport v.0.6.0 is currently broken due to an incompatibility:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/907

The maintainer suggests using the latest v0.5.0 until a fix is pushed out. Use:

npm uninstall passport

npm install passport@0.5

this worked fine for me.

Comment: Please use `npm install --save passport@0.5` to pin this version in your package.json or else when you are deploying this.. it may break on your deployments/post deploy testing flows.

Comment: No need of doing --save, In modern versions of npm (5.0.0 and later), you don't need to use the --save flag explicitly, as dependencies will be added to the appropriate section automatically.

Answer (score 10):

I found [philippkrauss's post](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/904#issuecomment-1307558283) of his suggested implementation to work while using passport 0.6.0.

```html
app.use(cookieSession({
    // ...
}))
// register regenerate & save after the cookieSession middleware initialization
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    if (request.session && !request.session.regenerate) {
        request.session.regenerate = (cb) => {
            cb()
        }
    }
    if (request.session && !request.session.save) {
        request.session.save = (cb) => {
            cb()
        }
    }
    next()
})
```

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/907

```
npm uninstall passport

npm install passport@0.5
```

Comment: This was my issue. I have a react 16.14.0 app in production and I ran npm audit fix. Sure enough it updated my passport to 0.6.0 thus crashing my app. This fix saved me in production and made me some money today. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I think this error happens because the passport use `req.session.regenerate()`  function internally ([source code link](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/sessionmanager.js)), `cookie-session` has not `regenerate` method and therefor passport throws the error.

There is also an issue on the `cookie-session` GitHub page that is related to `regenerate` function ([issue link](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/issues/166)).

If it is not important to keep the session on the client-side, you can keep it on the server-side, you can use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) for this, then you will not get the above error.

Comment: but where should i put this req.session.regenerate()?

Comment: Did you look at the source code link above? Passport internally use this function and when you use passport you also be  used this function indirectly
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/sessionmanager.js

Answer (score 3):

I faced the problem not quite long also... it seems to be a problem with the cookie-session package... To resolve this I used the express-session

```
// install the package
npm install express-session

const session = require('express-session')

app.use(session({
   secret: 'somethingsecretgoeshere',
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: true,
   cookie: { secure: true }
}));
```

Comment: This is not a solution. This uses MemoryStore by default which lives on the server side as opposed to cookie-session that stores data in the browser (cookie).

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(cookieSession({
    // ...
}))
// register regenerate & save after the cookieSession middleware initialization
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  if (request.session && !request.session.regenerate) {
    request.session.regenerate = (cb) => {
      cb()
    }
  }
  if (request.session && !request.session.save) {
    request.session.save = (cb) => {
      cb()
    }
  }
  next()
})
```